# Python: muliple projects in the same package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I want to have multiple Python projects in the same package. For example: `mycompany.parser`, `mycompany.database`. These projects have to be able to be installed separately. So a user can have only `mycompany.parser` or only `mycompany.database`, or both.

Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to achieve. You are describing *namespace packages*.

For instructions on how to create namespace packages, follow the guide here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

You may also want to review [*PEP 420 – Implicit Namespace Packages*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/).